# How much options are there to color a circular graph with $10,000$ nodes with $2023$ colors?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

How much options are there to color a circular graph with $10,000$ nodes with $2023$ colors ?

Let $ c_n $ the undirected simple circular graph on $n$ nodes.
$E=\big\{\{1,2\},\ldots,\{n-1,n\},\{n,1\}\big\}.$
How many options there are to paint $c_n$ if $n= 1000$ and we demand that each adjacent node has different colour?

I came to an estimation by using inclusion-exclusion principle and the binomial theorem, yet I am not certain this is right...
$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{10,000}\binom{10000}{k}(2023)^{10,000-k}\cdot(-1)^{k}=2022^{k}$
as also noted, the nodes are numbered so rotation and reflections do not apply here.

Comment: Please edit to cite the source for this problem.  Questions involving the current year often appear in exams and competitions.  That said, a natural starting point here would be to solve the problem for smaller $n$.

Comment: Note:  you should also indicate which symmetries you are taking into account.  If two colorings differ by a rotation, are they the same?  What if they differ by a reflection?

Comment: What is $k$ in your "estimation"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c_{n,k}$ be the number of proper colorings of a labeled circular graph with $n$ nodes using $k$ colors (i.e., colorings where no two adjacent nodes have the same color).  You can color the first node in $k$ ways; each subsequent node can be colored in $k-1$ ways; and the final node needs to be colored differently than the first.  But the number of ways to color the graph where the final node is the *same* color as the first is just $c_{n-1,k}$.  So $$c_{n,k}=k\cdot(k-1)^{n-1}-c_{n-1,k},$$
where the recursion terminates with $c_{1,k}=0$.  Expanding out, you find that
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
c_{n,k} &=& k\cdot(k-1)^{n-1}\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{k-1}+\frac{1}{(k-1)^2}-\ldots \pm \frac{1}{(k-1)^{n-2}}\right) \\ &=& (k-1)^n \pm (k-1),
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where the sign is $+$ for even $n$ and $-$ for odd $n$.

Comment: thank you!
we have not learned (yet) how to solve with recursion, but i have managed to understand because of your explanations how to use exclusion-inclusion in order to solve it properly.
thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The number of ways to colour the circular graph on $n$ nodes with $c$ colours should be $\text{trace}(A^{n})$ where $A$ is the $c \times c$ matrix with all diagonal entries $0$ and all off-diagonal entries $1$.

Comment: Nice ...........+1

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes (edited)